# Date is incorrect, displays Dec 31, 1969

Tags: php

```
function convertdate($date) {
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
return date("M j, Y g:ia", $date);
}
```

So, I really don't know what's wrong. I have the rest of the code it needs to be looked at too. How could I fix this to display the correct date.

Comment: It's a date not time.

Comment: what are you passing into this method? is it `null`?

Comment: Have you tried sending it the correct date?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Your right, the date. Still, it's incorrect.

Comment: @user2933926 what parameter you are passing into it?

Comment: I'm completely new to PHP and programmed this from a tutorial video on youtube. Parameter? It's greek to me.

Comment: @user2933926 How you are using this function ? from where you are getting this - "Dec 31, 1969"  convertdate("STRING_YOU_ARE_PASSING_HERE_IF_ANY") ??

Comment: This function is for displaying the date in which a post was posted. The date is appearing on the page that displays all the posts.

Comment: @Jazza Sorry, typing fast.

Comment: I can't see my comment anymore. Either SO is buggy or a moderator cowardly deleted it without mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php) function takes an integer timestamp (number of seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC) as its second argument. My guess is you are not passing an integer (or at least, not the right integer) to your function.

Try using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) instead, eg

```
function convertDate($date) {
    $dt = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
    return $dt->format('M j, Y g:ia');
}
```

Demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/EUXgwJ

The date string parsing in the `DateTime` constructor is somewhat US locale specific (eg mm/dd/yyyy by default). You may get better mileage by being able to specify an optional *format* parameter to use in `DateTime::createFromFormat`, for example

```
function convertDate($date, $format = null) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago');
    if ($format !== null) {
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date, $tz);
        if ($dt === false) {
            throw new Exception('Could not parse date / time string');
        }
    } else {
        $dt = new DateTime($date, $tz);
    }
    return $dt->format('M j, Y g:ia');
}
```

Now you can either let `DateTime` take its best guess at the date / time string or specifically tell it what format to use, eg

```
echo convertDate('1/11/2013', 'd/m/Y');
```

Demo #2 - http://codepad.viper-7.com/gMjYLO

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing in the `$date` variable.

Try this if you are passing it as a string

```
function convertdate($date) {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
  return date("M j, Y g:ia", strtotime($date));
}                              ^^^^
```

Note the strtotime() function